# Repetitive then/catch method on Javascript

Tags: javascript, react.js, vue.js

I have this function and looks ugly because there are a lot of "catch" doing the same. Any idea how to make it better?

```
saveUser: function(){
    let user_id = this.$route.params.user_id;
    let payload = this.user;

    updateUser(user_id, payload).then(response => {
        updateOrCreateAddresses(payload).then(response => {
            updateOrCreateBalances(payload).then(response => {
                this.success();
            }).catch(error => {
                this.showError(error)
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            this.showError(error)
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        this.showError(error)
    })
},
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your question has to [describe what you are actually trying to accomplish](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in as much detail as possible. With not much code and basically no context, it is unlikely to get meaningful reviews.

Comment: Hello @AlexV, I want to improve or make the code looks a bit better. Having the catches repeated may not be the best practice

Comment: My question was not what you expect from the review, but the type of application this code is used for (your use-case).

Answer (score 1):

As I am not sure on how your Promises work, this is what I can come up with.

To reduce your `catch` nesting you could make each promise return another promise. This would force you to have a general `.then` and a general `.catch` after your `updateUser` method.

I stubbed a bit of code here:

```
var updateUser = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("Promise one");
});

var updateOrCreateAddresses = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject("Promise two"); // e.g. replace reject with resolve to see it "pass"
});

var updateOrCreateBalances = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("Promise three");
});

var success = () => {
    alert("Success");
}

updateUser.then( x => {
    return updateOrCreateAddresses.then(y => {
        return updateOrCreateBalances.then(z => {
            return success;
        })
    })
})
.then(a => a())
.catch(err => alert(err));
```

What happens there? Each promise is returning another promise. If one promise fails, the promise will return the "error" to it's parent, where on `updateUser` the promise get's finally caught.